# Definition of POV sound

Tags: terminology

Does any one know any web sites that have a good glossary of definitions of audio terms? I am looking for a definition for "POV sound".

Answer (score 3):

POV sound is Point Of View sound... in other words, the sound as heard by a specific character. An example would be where a character has just been near an explosion and everything is muffled and we hear the ringing in his/her ears. Another common example would be when one character is talking to another and person being talked to "zones out" and the character talking becomes muffled, or very distant or completely silent. Often followed by a sudden return to "real" sound. One of the most famous POV sound situations  is the Predator, from any of the Predator Movies.

POV sound often involves removing rather than adding things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really checked out the net and found that there was little or nothing in the realm of POV. I knew the definition but I like to make sure I am absolutely on. 

Comment: I think just about every field uses SOME term or another in a non-standard way, so makes sense to check.

Answer (score 2):

Hey oinkaudio,

My Masters project was all about POV sound. If you fancy I can send you a copy of it. It may bore you to death though lol There's quite a few films in it I've referenced and further sources for reading if you were interested. Drop me a msg if you (or anyone) wants it!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a field recording-oriented glossary on my site, www.airbornesound.com...

http://www.airbornesound.com/sound-effects-definitions

I have POV on there, although it is in a field recording context, is that what you mean?

I've always thought POV to be:

"how the target sound is affected by the position of the microphone including distance, angle, or whether the recording is made inside or outside relative to the sound recorded"

A bit clunky maybe.  Feedback?

Anyway the glossary may be lacking a few terms so if anyone thinks there's others I should add let me know.

Paul Virostek

Answer (score 1):

Im my mind POV sound would just be binaural or surround audio recorded with either a dummy head setup or a traditional stereo mic(or array) setup. The term point of view lends itself more to video in conjunction with audio(view being the key word here)i.e. what you hear in relation to what you see (if an object is seen at your left and audio is coming from the right of the rear he audio does not match the POV)
I think subjective sound/audio would be a more fitting description.

anyhoo this is all imo

m.caldeira

Answer (score 1):

To me POV sound is pretty much like the binaural concept, except it is constructed to follow the POV of the image. The most important part of the POV lies in the stereo information, so that a pan of the image is reflected in a pan of the stereo image. If a car drives through the picture, the sound follows its position. If the camera shifts 90 degrees to the right, the whole sound image shifts 90 degrees to the right. If an actor starts a line of dialogue dead center and then walks to the left and behind the camera, his sound follows his position.

Children of Men has a lot of scenes, where the sound is created in this way.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.filmsound.org/terminology.htm

But there's nothing there for POV.

Comment: Yah, thanks. I checked this site thoroughly and found nothing. 